# Gitlab CI not pulling latest source

Tags: node.js, heroku, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have nodejs application in Gitlab and I tried to setup a CI with Gitlab to Heroku using  .gitlab-ci.yml. The code is committed successfully and the deploy is also successfully done to heroku. But the deployed codebase is not the latest one and I am not seeing any change in the deployed app even after making several changes.

Below is my file .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stage:
 type: deploy
 script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y ruby-dev ruby
  - gem install dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=APP-NAME --api-key=API-KEY
 only:
  - master
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please help me fix it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe this documentation will be useful: http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/examples/test-and-deploy-ruby-application-to-heroku.html